# usage of filter in Teradata, using abinitio

Tags: teradata

How to get the only numeric characters in teradata input table, using abinitio.

I have a requirement to pass the product number from alpha numeric input values.

For Input data:
          N345VM
          D5689NM
          T309MN
          R4567LK

I need the output as:

345
   5689
   309
   4567

Thanks,
Sharan

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just a task description.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on TD14 you can utilize a Regular Expression to replace groups of non-digits by a single blank:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(col, '[^0-9]+', ' ')
```

Comment: Or, if you're not on TD14, and you can add UDFs: [TD Provided UDFs](http://developer.teradata.com/blog/madmac/2010/03/a-few-basic-scalar-string-udfs).  The `eReplaceChar` function will work for your purposes, I think.  It's been a while since I've messed with these though.

Answer (score 0):

Abinitio is simply unloading your data as per the select expression provided. If you are able to write a select expression fulfilling your requirement then Abinitio will return you the expected data.